# SettingWithCopyWarning: modifications to a method of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, warnings, series

I have a series like that. (ser)

```
0   2019-01-01 09:20:00-04:00
1   2019-01-02 09:20:00-04:00
2   2019-01-03 09:20:00-04:00
3   2019-01-04 09:20:00-04:00
4   2019-01-05 09:20:00-04:00
```

Another like that. (new_ser)

```
2   2019-01-01 09:55:11-05:00
```

Another like that. (mask_new_ser)

```
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   False
4   False
```

I am trying to get a final series like that:

```
0   2019-01-01 09:20:00-04:00
1   2019-01-02 09:20:00-04:00
2   2019-01-01 09:55:11-05:00
3   2019-01-04 09:20:00-04:00
4   2019-01-05 09:20:00-04:00
```

With the following line is working fine.

```
ser[mask_new_ser.index] = new_ser[mask_new_ser.index]
```

But I am getting the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: modifications to a method of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded. Change values on the original.
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

How can I correct that?

Comment: Add .copy() at the end the line where I use tz_localize was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in npandas 0.25.0:

If need set new values to existing `Series` by index of new appended `Series` use:

```
ser.loc[new_ser.index] = new_ser
print (ser)
0    2019-01-01 09:20:00-04:00
1    2019-01-02 09:20:00-04:00
2    2019-01-01 09:55:11-05:00
3    2019-01-04 09:20:00-04:00
4    2019-01-05 09:20:00-04:00
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Another solution with `mask`, but it working only if match `True`s values indices with index of appended `new_ser`:

```
ser.loc[mask_new_ser] = new_ser
```

But because different timezones, lost datetimes and get `Timestamp`s objects:

```
print (ser.apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
3    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
4    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
Name: a, dtype: object
```

If want datetimes, is possible with converting to `UTC`:

```
ser = pd.to_datetime(ser, utc=True)
print (ser)
0   2019-01-01 13:20:00+00:00
1   2019-01-02 13:20:00+00:00
2   2019-01-01 14:55:11+00:00
3   2019-01-04 13:20:00+00:00
4   2019-01-05 13:20:00+00:00
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Comment: It did not work. 
Add .copy() at the end the line where I use tz_localize was the solution for me.

Comment: @Alfonso_MA - What is your pandas version?